# Is it necessary that an Electric Field becomes $1/K$ times inside a dielectric in all cases?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, dielectric

Suppose in space, there is an electric field. Now we introduce a dielectric medium in space with dielectric constant $K$. Is it necessary that an Electric Field will become $1/K$ times inside a dielectric in all cases, independent of the distribution and shape of the medium?

Is it a general rule that the electric field becomes $1/K$ times inside a dielectric medium, or it happens only in certain conditions? If it happens only in certain conditions, then what are those conditions? And what happens when those conditions are not met?